# Open dialog box prevents windows shutdown

Tags: c#, windows

I have a C# GUI app that shows a message using `MessageBox.Show(Message);`, however if the user fails to click on this, and then requests shutting down the PC, it blocks the shutdown.
How do I prevent my open dialog box from blocking the shutdown?

Comment: Maybe auto-close it when it loses focus?

Comment: What version of windows is it?

Comment: This is normal behavior. A `MessageBox` is informing the user of something that requires them to do something (even if it's just clicking `OK` to acknowledge they've seen the dialog). Tell your user to do what they're supposed to do and close the `MessageBox` before trying to shut down their system, or use your own WinForm instead that can watch for and respond to the [WM_QUERYENDSESSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376890%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message and close itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using WinForms since you didn't mention WPF. You can't use a MessageBox if you want to control closing behavior. You'll have to build your own screen to act as a message box and use the ShowDialog method to display it. Your screen can handle the FormClosing event to detect when Windows is shutting down:

```
    private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
```

So you'll want to allow the screen to close in this case and perhaps take other action for other types of close signals. To prevent the screen from closing, set the Cancel flag on the `FormClosingEventArgs` parameter to true;